# Newcommand returning a boolean value

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

I'm using `etoolbox`. How can I create a new command that returns a boolean value? For example if I create the following command:

```
\newcommand\ifkeyempty[1]{
    \def\novalue{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
    \def\empty{}%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}{\value}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefequal{\value}{\empty}} or test {\ifdefequal{\value}{\novalue}}}{true}{false}%
}
```

I would like to be able to use it in a boolean expression like this:

```
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyempty{/keyname}} or ... }{expression is true}{expression is false}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You shouldn't use `\value` to begin with, because it's already an important command in LaTeX.

Comment: I suppose, that you have to use a boolean variable or ('flag') which is used globally, but this is not a very nice approach: `\providebool{MyKeyFlag}` and `\boolfalse{MyKeyFlag}` or `\booltrue{MyKeyFlag}`

Comment: Please add an MWE also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! It was actually easy! I just removed the clauses that should be performed if the expression is true or false in the definition of the command. It now works both in tests like `\ifboolexpr` and by using it directly like `\ifkeyempty{<key>}{<true>}{<false>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pgfkeys{
    /foo/.initial,
    /bar/.initial,
}

\newcommand\ifkeyempty[1]{
    \def\novalue{\pgfkeysnovalue}%
    \def\empty{}%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}{\keyvalue}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefequal{\keyvalue}{\empty}} or test {\ifdefequal{\keyvalue}{\novalue}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyempty{/foo}} and test {\ifkeyempty{/bar}}}{expression is true}{expression is false}
\ifkeyempty{/foo}{foo is empty}{foo is not empty}

\pgfkeys{/foo=value1}
\ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyempty{/foo}} and test {\ifkeyempty{/bar}}}{expression is true}{expression is false}
\ifkeyempty{/foo}{foo is empty}{foo is not empty}

\pgfkeys{/bar=value2}
\ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyempty{/foo}} and test {\ifkeyempty{/bar}}}{expression is true}{expression is false}
\ifkeyempty{/foo}{foo is empty}{foo is not empty}

\pgfkeys{/foo=}
\ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyempty{/foo}} and test {\ifkeyempty{/bar}}}{expression is true}{expression is false}
\ifkeyempty{/foo}{foo is empty}{foo is not empty}

\pgfkeys{/bar=}
\ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyempty{/foo}} and test {\ifkeyempty{/bar}}}{expression is true}{expression is false}
\ifkeyempty{/foo}{foo is empty}{foo is not empty}

\end{document}
```